# Create a JSON string with number of significant figures / decimal places based on key IOS OBJ C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I need to upload JSON data from an app (IOS) to the backend server.

The goal is to optimise the size of the upload packet which is JSON encoded as a NSString.  The string is currently about 5MB but contains mostly doubles which have more precision than necessary.

The size of the packet can be reduced by around 40-50% by removing unnecessary decimal places in doubles.  This has to be customisable based on the key.

What is the best way to create a JSON string with different numbers of significant figures or decimal places depending on the key.

Comment: Use `NSNumberFormatter` or `stringWithFormat` to convert the `double` to a string with the desired decimals.

Comment: Scale your values so that they can be transmitted as integers.

Comment: if your backend server supports zipped content you can send compressed data instead of a plain text file.

Comment: @Thorsten already zipping ,trying to zip less :-)

Comment: @rmaddy not sure how I would do that when I'm trying to turn a really big dictionary into JSON using JSONKit

Comment: @HotLicks this is probably the answer, but it could be far nicer.  I might change JSONKit to do what I want :-(

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do some experiments. Let's say you want to send data with two decimal digits, like 3.14 instead of pi. You know you have to turn all numbers into NSNumber. You would turn x into a number with two decimals by writing

```
double asDouble = 3.141592653;    
NSNumber* asNumber = @(round (asDouble * 100.0) / 100.0);
```

However, you need to check that this always works; with some bad luck this could send 3.140000000000000000000001 to your server.

Obviously you can replace the 100.0 with 1000.0 etc. Do *not* replace the division with a multiplication by 0.01 because that will increase rounding errors and the chance that you get tons of decimal digits.

You might check what happens if you write

```
NSNumber* asNumber = @((float) asDouble);
```

If NSJSONSerialization is clever enough, it will send fewer decimals.

Comment: Thanks gnasher, the problem with NSNumber is that floating point numbers are not exact and when i tried this many numbers were still 16 digits long.  I need one more digit than a float has...